# Protractor config onPrepare method makes asynchronous call. How can do I block test starting?

Tags: node.js, protractor

My protractor config file needs to perform some asynchronous work (e.g., downloading libraries and extra filesystem preparation). How can I force protractor to block until all this asynchronous work is complete.

Here is a simplification of what I have and what I need:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

exports.config = {
    onPrepare: function () {
        if (noPreparationNeeded()) {
            return;
        }
        http.get('http://mydriver.company.com', function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(data) {
                file.write(data);
            }).on('end', function() {
                file.end();
                console.log('Driver download complete');
            });
         })
    }
};
```

As it currently is, tests will start before the download is complete. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need q to return a promise. Here is an example:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/953faf7ebee345f686bfedff61ebcb29c5170083/spec/onPreparePromiseConf.js

Comment: `onPrepare: function() {
    return q.fcall(function() {
      browser.params.password = '12345';
    }).delay(1000);
}`. Copying the answer here just in case the original gist ever goes away.